# Tails v3.7 using VM = user agent Windows 7?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tails, windows, linux, fingerprinting

I'm trying to use Tails v3.7 via virtual machine.
I've already tried VirtualBox, and VMware.

And everything is OK, but..... when I've visited website https://2ip.ru to check my IP-address, I've noticed that my OS is not some version of Linux (Debian, Ubuntu, Tails, etc.) but Windows 7.

In the settings of choosing the type of OS, I choose Linux, and already tried almost everything: Ubuntu, Debian, x32, x64, Other OS x64, etc...

I'm not an expert of Tails at all. But how is that possible?

Where does this fingerprint come from?

Yes, Windows 7 is my OS, from where I'm launching VM with Tails.

But, I don't understand how Tails does not replace this "windows" fingerprint with some Linux fingerprint.

What can fix this OS leak?

I know, that there are some "User Agent Switcher"s extensions can be downloaded for Tor-Browser. And it seems like they do their work. But is it 100% safe? Can I trust them?

**Or, first of all, how can I prevent my "Windows 7" OS fingerprint from "leaking" ?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All Tor Browser users have the same User Agent. That user agents claims that you are using Windows even if you are not.

You aren't leaking anything.